# Safari overflow/visibility and overflow/display bug (element remains visible)

Tags: html, css, safari

I've come across a strange bug in Safari browser rendering.

When I hover over element (green `.hover`) which makes its child element (pink `.pop`) visible, the child stays visible even after the hover has ended. It's visible but not selectable - I can select text "behind" the child element as you can see in the screenshot below.

[image]

HTML:

```
<div class="hover">
    Hover me! (display)

    <div class="pop pop--display">
        I will cover your content in Safari indefinitely
    </div>
</div>

<div class="content">
    Content
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.hover {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.pop {
    position: absolute;
    top: 80%;
    left: 10px;
}

.hover:hover {
    overflow: visible;
}

.pop--display {
    display: none;
}

.hover:hover .pop--display {
    display: block;
}
```

It seems to be caused by changing `overflow` `hidden`/`visible` of the parent element together with changing of `display` `none`/`block` (or `visibility` `hidden/visible`) of the child element. I came across this bug using JavaScript but mere CSS `:hover` can reproduce it.

Tested on Safari **8.0.6** (10600.6.3) and **9.0.1** (11601.2.7.2).

```css
/* basic styling and formating */
.hover {
    padding: 10px 0;
    width: 200px;
    background: green;
}

.pop {
    padding: 20px;
    height: 90px;
    width: 140px;
    background: pink;
}

.content {
    width: 200px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    height: 100px;
    background: grey;
}

.test + .test {
    margin-top: 30px;
}


/* overflows and positioning */
.hover {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.pop {
    position: absolute;
    top: 80%;
    left: 10px;
}

.hover:hover {
    overflow: visible;
}


/* variations */
.pop--display {
    display: none;
}
.hover:hover .pop--display {
    display: block;
}

.pop--visibility {
    visibility: hidden;
}
.hover:hover .pop--visibility {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">                                                                          
    <div class="hover">                                                                     
        Hover me! (default)                                                                 
    
        <div class="pop">                                                                   
            I will cover your content in Safari indefinitely                                
        </div>                                                                              
    </div>
    
    <div class="content">                                                                   
        Content                                                                             
    </div>                                                                                  
</div>                                                                                      

<div class="test">                                                                          
    <div class="hover">                                                                     
        Hover me! (display)                                                                 

        <div class="pop pop--display">                                                      
            I will cover your content in Safari indefinitely                                
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="content">                                                                   
        Content                                                                             
    </div>
</div>

<div class="test">                                                                          
    <div class="hover">                                                                     
        Hover me! (visibility)                                                              

        <div class="pop pop--visibility">                                                   
            I will cover your content in Safari indefinitely                                
        </div>                                                                              
    </div>                                                                                  

    <div class="content">                                                                   
        Content                                                                             
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution I could came to is to use `opacity` with `pointer-events`. I expect `opacity: 0; pointer-events: none` to act the same way as `visibility: hidden`.

But I'm still not sure if this is a right approach...

The corresponding CSS is:

```
.pop--opacity {
    opacity: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
}
.hover:hover .pop--opacity {
    opacity: 1;
    pointer-events: auto;
}
```

```css
/* basic styling and formating */
.hover {
    padding: 10px 0;
    width: 200px;
    background: green;
}

.pop {
    padding: 20px;
    height: 90px;
    width: 140px;
    background: pink;
}

.content {
    width: 200px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    height: 100px;
    background: grey;
}

.test + .test {
    margin-top: 30px;
}



/* overflows and positioning */
.hover {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}   

.pop {
    position: absolute;
    top: 80%;
    left: 10px;
}   

.hover:hover {
    overflow: visible;
}   


.pop--opacity {
    opacity: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
}
.hover:hover .pop--opacity {
    opacity: 1;
    pointer-events: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
    <div class="hover">
        Hover me! (opacity)

        <div class="pop pop--opacity">
            I will cover your content in Safari indefinitely
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="content">
        Content
    </div>
</div>
```